# Can I set two different timers inside one trigger in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a form that has a When New Form Instance Trigger on it, so I'm wondering how can I set two different timers on that trigger with different lengths, that do different actions when they end?

My try:

***WHEN_NEW_FORM_INSTANCE***

```
DECLARE    
  timer_pocetak TIMER;
  timer_zatvori TIMER;    
BEGIN    
  timer_pocetak:= CREATE_TIMER('POCETAK',60000,NO_REPEAT);   
  timer_zatvori:= CREATE_TIMER('KRAJ',270000,NO_REPEAT);    
end;
```

***WHEN_TIMER_EXPIRED***

```
DECLARE    
    v_timer_name VARCHAR2(100);    
BEGIN    
    v_timer_name :=GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY (timer_name);

  IF v_timer_name = 'POCETAK' THEN    
    procedure...        
  ELSIF V_TIMER_NAME = 'KRAJ' THEN    
    DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(NULL);
    DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(NULL, NULL);
    EXIT_FORM(NO_COMMIT, FULL_ROLLBACK);    
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: I did but they didn't work

Comment: please update the question rather than adding such comments here.

Comment: Yep, click [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69279692/edit) in order to edit your request and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have more than one timer.  However, I would recommend you carefully consider what to do if the timers all try to expire at the same exact time. In this case, although seeing that all expired should happen, the order in which they are reported may be somewhat random.

Are you aware that you can ask your Oracle Forms questions directly to Oracle employees and other Forms users?  Check out the Oracle Forms Forum for the latest information about Forms.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/forms